# Is it possible to detect music controls

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, controls

I have a side project playing with some music controls on my iPhone. I know that i can detect volume up/down keys or track changes for Apple music app. Does anyone know if this is also possible to do for any other music apps like Spotify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MPRemoteCommandCenter` to detect the controls. I'm not sure if it will work with Spotify but it's definitely worth a shot.